# Why Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFF) returns ffffffffffffffff

Tags: java, twos-complement

This is what I see in java, and it puzzles me.

`Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFF)` returns `ffffffffffffffff`

Similarly, `0xFFFFFFFF` and `Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFF", 16)` are unequal.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with java, but I think 0xFFFFFFFF is interpreted as normal int (+/- 2^32-1), so this creates overflow and that is why it returns what you think is incorrect.
As for second part, those two numbers don't have same amount of F's, so that me be the reason

Comment: @enoyhs Yeah, my bad about the wrong F count, fixed that.

Comment: I'll just mention that for a long-term C# programmer this seems rather insidious on the part of Java. In C# the literal constant 0xFFFFFFFF is considered to be a uint, not an int. So then a simple copy-and-paste of a bit-manipulating expression from C# to Java can result in a nasty bug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As others have said, `0xFFFFFFFF` evaluates to the **int** value `-1`, which is promoted to a `long`.

To get the result you were expecting, qualify the constant with the `L` suffix to indicate it should be treated as a `long`, i.e. `Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFFL)`.

Comment: Marking as answer because of the "promoted" - that's when the penny dropped.

Answer (score 11):

This:

```
Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFF)
```

is equivalent to:

```
Long.toHexString(-1)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL)
```

Basically, the problem is that you're specifying a negative `int` value, which is then being converted to the equivalent negative *long* value, which consists of "all Fs". If you really *want* 8 Fs, you should use:

```
Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFFL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, `Long` in java is 64-bits long! `0xFFFFFFFF` means `-1` as an `int`, when written in 64 bits, it's `ffffffffffffffff`.

However, if the number were unsigned, the string would also be `ffffffff` [but there's no `unsigned` in java].

Comment: Why `0xFFFFFFFF` is `-1`? How can one represent the number returned by `Long.parseLong("FFFFFFFF", 16)` in hexa?

Comment: `int` is 32-bits, so `FFFFFFFF` == `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`. When you interpret it as a signed integer, it's obviously `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

`0xFFFFFFFF` is an `int` literal. When using `int`s (32 bit in Java) `0xFFFFFFFF` equals `-1`. What your code does:

- the compiler parses `0xFFFFFFFF` as an `int` with value `-1`
- the java runtime calls `Long.toHexString(-1)` (the `-1` get "casted" automatically to a `long` which is expected here)

And when using `long`s (64 bit in Java) `-1` is `0xffffffffffffffff`.

`long` literals are post-fixed by an `L`. So your expected behaviour is written in Java as:

```
Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFFL)
```

and `Long.toHexString(0xFFFFFFFFL)` is `"ffffffff"`